# How can I prove this equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

My prof put this equation on the board, without any kind of explanation or proof. When I asked him for one, he didn't really give me a solid answer.

$$w = r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$$

Then

$w^n = r^n(\cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta)$ for $n \in \mathbb{R}$

I would try to prove this, but it's a bit beyond me considering I learn't what a complex number is a week ago. Please don't use Euler's Theorem.

**EDIT**: I ended up using induction since the formula is not valid for non-integers.

Comment: I think that even if someone doesn't use Euler's formula directly, it will be used indirectly anyway.

Comment: Have you tried proving it by *induction* ? :)

Comment: If you don't want to use Euler, try using induction. It's straightforward.

Comment: @IvoTerek My proof suggested that to me, but wouldn't that only work for integer $n$? I was hoping for a proof for all real $n$.

Comment: For all real numbers I think you will only get it using Euler's formula. Not sure, though.

Comment: I think you just need to accept that $e^{it}=\cos t + i\sin t$ and experiment with it to become more familiar with its properties. You won't survive the course if you refuse to use that. It's fundamental.

Comment: You may wish to read the wikipedia page on [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula), especially the section titled "Failure for non-integer powers".

Comment: @MPW The thing is that we haven't been formally been introduced to Euler's Theorem yet, so I was hoping for one without it.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Wow, I wasn't aware of that. I suppose induction will have to do. Thank you.

Comment: @MPW Turns out it doesn't work with non-integers, thanks for the help.

Comment: @IvoTerek Turns out it doesn't work with non-integers, thanks for the help.

Comment: I didn't know that, too. Nice.

Comment: Note that as you have only just started studying complex numbers, it will be (and should be!) unclear in some cases what $w^n$ means.  It's pretty easy to understand that $w^3$ means $w\times w\times w$, but what about $w^\pi$?  Or even $w^i$?  These will have to wait until later in your course.

Comment: No, actually, the formula *is* valid in a sense for any $n\in \mathbb R$. However, it only gives one of the possible values. For nonintegral $n$, the function is multivalued. But for nonreal $n$, this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you've been taught the form $e^{i\theta} = cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta$).
If yes, then $$w = re^{i\theta}$$ and $$w^n = r^ne^{in\theta} = r^n(cos(n\theta) + i sin(n\theta))$$

Maybe your prof did not give you the explanation because he haven't taught you this form yet. I don't remember very well what comes first in the math program between complex numbers and exponentials (plus it can depend on the country).